# C# WPF -- Mouse click spawning shape from the center of the click

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouseclick-event

I'm working on a practice application that adds blue squares to a canvas when you click inside the canvas. One of the requirements is that **the shape is added at that point with the mouse representing the center of the new shape.**

By default, the click point of the mouse will be the   top left of the square. Is there a way to make the square spawn from the center of the mouse click instead of the top right?

This is how i currently add my squares to the canvas:

```
    private void canvasArea_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Shape Rendershape = null;

        switch (Shape1)
        {
            case SelectedShape.Rectangle:
                Rendershape = new Rectangle() 
                { 
                    Fill = Brushes.Blue, 
                    Height = num1, 
                    Width = num2
                };
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        Canvas.SetLeft(Rendershape, e.GetPosition(canvasArea).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(Rendershape, e.GetPosition(canvasArea).Y);
        canvasArea.Children.Add(Rendershape);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is shift the rectangle by half the rectangle's width and height, see following code:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(Rendershape, e.GetPosition(canvasArea).X - ( Rendershape.Width / 2.0 ) );
Canvas.SetTop(Rendershape, e.GetPosition(canvasArea).Y - ( Rendershape.Height / 2.0 ) );
```